# How to include a file to python

Tags: python, include

I have a subfile, for example ex1.h,
which contains some of my code, for example `print('Test something')`.

Now I want to include it to my main file, i.e. main.py, such that

```
#include 'ex1.h'
```

And when I run the python file main.py, I want it to print out the message: `Test something`.
Is there any way to do that with python?

Comment: Do you mean importing a C/C++ header from Python code? Or do you mean importing another python file.

Comment: Also see Python's tutorial on modules: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Hi zrfank, because my python code is long, so I want to slit it out, so that I can call it back. For example, I have a list of names, and I want to print them: print('abc'), print('ads'), print('fde'),...., and so forth. I want to slit all of print('...') in another file, so that I can easy to add new name without open my main python file. (But I do not want to make a file to read a list of name)